# Android: Button shift animation

Tags: android, android-animation

For example, let's say I there is one button in the top right of the screen.  When the user does some random action, two more buttons appear to the right of the first button, adjusting the position of the first button so together they are centered within that space.  Instead of the final layout appearing instantaneously, I want to see the first button shifting/sliding towards the left to make space for the two new buttons.  How do I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of animation ,

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "x", nextX);
        animation1.setDuration(1400);
```

or you can use translatorAnimation class this way you can move your button.
Hope it helps.